# Exibir div após um certo tempo, com setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando colocar `setTimeOut` em uma `div` em javascript, mas não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum!

Meu código :

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 if(document.all){}
else document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);document.onmousemove=mouse;function mouse(e)
{if(navigator.appName=='Netscape'){xcurs=e.pageX;ycurs=e.pageY;}else{xcurs=event.clientX;ycurs=event.clientY;}
document.getElementById('mime').style.left=(xcurs-230)+'px';document.getElementById('mime').style.top=(ycurs-150)+'px';}
</script>

</head>
<div id="mime">
<iframe style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:605px; height:250px;

float:left;" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" src="http://migre.me/qaksC"></iframe>
</div>
```

Estou querendo que isso apareça depois um certo tempo, e a única function que eu acho que serve para isso é a `setTimeOut`, já tentei de diversos modos mas nenhum resultado, tentei assim :

```
setTimeout('document.getElementById('mime')', 60000);

document.getElementById('mime').setTimeout(60000);

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 if(document.all){}
else document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);document.onmousemove=mouse;function mouse(e)
{if(navigator.appName=='Netscape'){xcurs=e.pageX;ycurs=e.pageY;}else{xcurs=event.clientX;ycurs=event.clientY;}
document.getElementById('mime').style.left=(xcurs-230)+'px';document.getElementById('mime').style.top=(ycurs-150)+'px';}
</script>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('mime');
}, 60000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div id="mime">
    <iframe style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:605px; height:250px; float:left;" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" src="http://migre.me/qaksC"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
// O HTML da div precisa estar acima.
// Esconde a div no início
var div = document.getElementById('mime');
div.style.display = 'none';

// Mostra a div após 1 minuto
setTimeout(function() {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}, 60000);
</script>
```

Comment: De certo cara, obrigado !