# Fazer Div aparecer 4 segundos depois do site carregado

Tags: javascript, html

Como posso fazer para uma `div` aparecer 4 segundos depois do site carregar?

Comment: Veja essa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67872/exibir-div-ap%C3%B3s-um-certo-tempo-com-settimeout

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar este código usando jQuery:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Conteudo normal fora da div<br><br>

<div ID="teste" style="display:none;">

Conteudo a ser exibido apos 4 segundos

</div>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
     setTimeout(carregar, 4000);
});

function carregar() {
    $('#teste').show();
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Se não quiser usar jQuery:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout(carregar, 4000);">

Conteudo normal fora da div<br><br>

<div ID="teste" style="display:none;">
Conteudo a ser exibido apos 4 segundos
</div>


<script>

function carregar() {
    document.getElementById("teste").style.display="block";
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mano é 4 segundos....kkk É nois...

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer exibir um div já existente que esteja oculto terá que usar `setTimeout` e `document.getElementById` ou `document.getElementsByClassName` ou `document.querySelector`, por exemplo:

> Note que `setTimeout` usa milissegundos, então tem que multiplicar os segundos por 1000 pra torna-lo em milissegundos

```js
window.onload = function() {
     var segundos = 4;
     setTimeout(function () {
         var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
         foo.className = ""; //Remove a classe hide
     }, segundos * 1000);
};
```

```css
.hide {
   display: none;
}

#foo {
    background-color: #f00;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="hide">Olá mundo!</div>
```

Se quiser criar um elemento dinamicamente então terá que usar `document.createElement`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
     var segundos = 4;
     setTimeout(function () {
         //Cria um novo elemento
         var novoDiv = document.createElement("div");
       
         //pega o elemento existente que vai receber o novo div
         var alvo = document.getElementById("target");
       
         //Adiciona um texto ao DIV
         novoDiv.textContent = "Conteudo de texto";
   
         //Adiciona o novo div ao elemento existente
         alvo.appendChild(novoDiv);
     }, segundos * 1000);
};
```

```css
#target div {
    background-color: #f00;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Nota que você pode trocar `textContent` por `innerHTML` se quiser adicionar qualquer tipo de HTML ao seu novo div

### Recomendo que estude estas referencias:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

Answer (score 1):

Patrão vê se ajuda:

A função em questão é a "setTimeout()" do Javascript. Dependendo do efeito que deseja pode customizar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<p>Nem precisa clicar,aguarde 4 segundos, e veja "Olá".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Clica e aguarda</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Olá, viu demorou 4 segundos, relógio Suiço!"); }, 4000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Outro exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="timedText()()">

<p>Nem precisa clicar, veja a div aparecer, e depois mudar</p>

<button onclick="timedText()">Mostra Div, com mistério</button>
<div id="txt"></div>

<script>
function timedText() {
    var x = document.getElementById("txt");
    setTimeout(function(){ x.innerHTML="2 seconds" }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){ x.innerHTML="4 seconds" }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function(){ x.innerHTML="6 seconds" }, 6000);
    setTimeout(function(){ x.innerHTML="Viu com mistério é mais dahora !" }, 8000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Referência aqui <<<<<<<<](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Este código carrega a div mediante ao clique no botão, não ao carregamento do site como ele pediu.

Comment: Pronto patrão, vê se ficou igual se queria...Se tiver de acordo alguma das respostas, num esquece de validar...Vlw ;)